# Remove part of a column, if its in a specific Column number. (The column has a variable)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv with lines like this:

```
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,Sentence Skills 104,,Elementary Algebra 38,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 101,College Level Math 56
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,Reading Comprehension 102,,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 118,College Level Math 97
```

I want to remove the word "Reading Comprehension" but leave the number, but only if its in column 6, if its in any other column, leave it alone.

Once again the variable is stumping me, I know how to remove it from the specific column if I know the number, but not remove the word and leave the number when I don't know the number

```
awk -v old="Reading Comprehension 102" -v new="" -v col=6 '$col==old{$col=new} 1' FS="," OFS="," mergedfile.csv > testmerg.csv
```

Thank you for the help,

Comment: I love all three answers. @Ed Morton showed me how to make my current syntax works, thank you. anubhava showed me a much cleaner way to do it. and josifoski gave me a sed example (which I'm actually more familiar with). I will have to select Ed Morton as the answer, but I might end up using anubhava :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-using your awk variable definitions:

```
$ awk -v old="Reading Comprehension " -v new="" -v col=6 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(old,new,$col)} 1' file
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,Sentence Skills 104,,Elementary Algebra 38,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 101,College Level Math 56
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,102,,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 118,College Level Math 97
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I wonder if you have a commission for every book Arnold sells ;D

Comment: I actually have the book, just got it a couple of days ago. Been reading it and googling at the same time. Which is why I have an idea of how to do certain things with awk, but don't have the whole solution figured out.

Comment: Yes, get the book. It's a thick manual but you may become an [g]awk master like Arnold and Ed. From following Ed and others on SO, it seems there's probably nothing that [g]awk can't do. Thank you Ed and others for contributing to SO awk!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/Reading Comprehension */, "", $6)} 1' file.csv
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,Sentence Skills 104,,Elementary Algebra 38,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 101,College Level Math 56
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,102,,,,
Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,,,,Elementary Algebra 118,College Level Math 97
```

Comment: You that's right, col # and search text both can be supplier from arguments using `-v argName=argValue`

Answer (score 2):

Let give sed a chance (althought is not it's domain)

```
echo "Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,Reading Comprehension 102,,,," |  
sed -r 's/(([^,]*,){5})Reading Comprehension /\1/'
```

Last,First,A00XXXXXX,1492-01-10,2015-06-17,102,,,,

or by *Ed Morton's* suggestion for using variables

```
old="Reading Comprehension"  
new=""  
col=6  
sed -r 's/(([^,]*,){'"$((col-1))"'})'"$old"' /\1'"$new"'/'
```

Comment: yes Ed, why not to keep assembly for fun and mind bingling ups googling